# Correct way to add a string property to existing Powershell object?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

So for example, I have a custom object for `$server`. I want to create a new property, `$server.output` to contain multi line output of varying size. What is the best approach to take? There doesn't seem to be any straight forward information on the web around how to add simple string properties to objects?

FYI I am using powershell v4, but it would be nice to have a solution for v5 too.

Comment: Take a look at the Add-Member cmdlet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Outside of re-creating the object or ensuring the property exists on object initialization, you have to use `Add-Member` to create new properties on a `pscustomobject`:

```
# alternatively, use `-Force` on `Add-Member`
if (-not ($obj | Get-Member -Name output))
{
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name output -Value ''
}
```

Supported in v3+:

```
$obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName output -NotePropertyValue '' -Force
```

Add multiple members:

```
$obj | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{output = ''; output1 = ''} -Force
```

---

#### [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-5.1)